# Horizontal and vertical scrolling in single page

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js, vertical-scrolling, singlepage

I am trying to combine vertical and horizontal scroll in a single page.I have 3 *divs* and in one of them I want to use [jquery.horizonScroll.js](http://trgraglia.github.io/jquery.horizonScroll.js/demo/index.html)

But when I scroll the *horizontal div* all other 3 *divs* scroll too.Is it possible to make it work or is it just I waste of time? I know about [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) but don't want to use it.

Comment: Any reason why not using fullpage.js? Seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Does Fullpage have Mousewheel and touchSwipe Scroll ?

Comment: And also if I make slider section fp-auto-height left and right keyboard arrows don't work.

Comment: yep, it has vertical mouse wheel support and touch horizontal and vertical one. Maybe the touch one is not as you expect? Or you might want to have mouse wheel for horizontal slides? Regarding `fp-auto-height` and the control arrows, it seems to work as expected [here](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1205/).

Comment: Yes, I mean mouse wheel for horizontal slide, but it's not as important as touch swipe. does it support scrolling with mouse , for desktop versions I want to hide arrows and scroll with mouse.

Comment: nop, it doesn't provide it. But I believe it would be easier to modify the plugin or to code it yourself by using fullpgae.js methods than trying to accomodate horizonScroll.js for your purposes. And well, you can always ask for a customization as [commented here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/316).

Answer (score 0):

fullPage.js provides now the [Horizontal Extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrollHorizontally.html) for it.